# Else is never necessary for an array operation

Tags: php, phpmd

PHPMD says 'Else is never necessary' for the following code:

```
if (!isset($myArray[$myKey])) { // or in_array
    $myArray[$myKey] = $myValue;
} else {
    $myArray[$myKey] += $myValue;
}
```

Is it possible to write this code in a cleaner way without a PHPMD warning?

I know "? ... : ..." is an option but it's still if/else.

Comment: Maybe you already have an assurance that your array never has that specific key? Context matters, namely how you initialize and use/return your array. Can you share more code? More often that not that rule is advising you that you can rewrite your logic in a more "clean" way.

Comment: Is phpmd not interfered by error syntax with `$myArray[$myKey]]`? The last `]` is to remove.

Comment: What is $myKey and $myVaue? is it defined?

Comment: Possible bug in MD? As you said, we can use shorthand syntaxes but it is still if-else, like null coalescing operator or ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the array key is not set if so create that key with a default value   (0 if the array holds numbers or '' for string ). This will remove some duplicate code like `$myArray[$myKey] += $myValue;`.

```php
if (!isset($myArray[$myKey])) { // or in_array
    $myArray[$myKey] = 0; // if the array contains numbers or '' for string
}
 
$myArray[$myKey] += $myValue;
```

Comment: Good answer, thank you, but I still believe that it's weird to forbid a functionality by all means, which is defined in the language context.

Comment: @tolga it's not forbidden and you can ignore it. It's a matter of what that tool defines as a "good practice". Check this [issue](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/issues/288) for more details.